# .net assembly interop exceptions handling

Tags: .net, delphi, com

I am calling a .Net assembly from a Delphi project using COM interop.

Can I catch .Net exceptions in Delphi thrown by the assembly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

COM does not work with .NET exceptions but with [`HRESULT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231198%28PROT.13%29.aspx) values. So there is no way you can catch .NET exceptions at Delphi side. You just receive a HRESULT with an error value. If you are lucky you will get an HRESULT with a specific error value so you know what has gone wrong, if you're unlucky, you will get some generic HRESULT value.

Comment: hm, if i call procedure, it will return nothing, but it can throw exception, so i can not do anything?

Comment: Every COM method returns an HRESULT value. I don't know how COM interop at the .NET side is handled, but I guess that even when a procedure goes wrong, it will return an HRESULT with an error value.

Comment: @eba: perhaps you are referring to Delphi's Safecall. The safecall calling convention encapsulates COM error handling, When calling a safecall function from Delphi code, Delphi automatically checks the returned HRESULT and raises an exception if necessary.

Comment: Over 7 years later... is this still true? This library: https://sourceforge.net/p/dotnetruntimelibraryfordelphi/wiki/Home/ claims that it can "handle .Net exceptions and access all .Net exception properties including exception type name, StackTrace etc"